# How to find an error on csv file using pandas and jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i'm using jupyter and pandas to understand some patterns in a database, I have 2 date formats in the table, 'create_time' and 'active_time'.

If I use

```
pf['create_time'] = pd.to_datetime(pf['create_time'],format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    455             try:
--> 456                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    457                 dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-3881c9561812> in <module>
----> 1 pf['create_time'] = pd.to_datetime(pf['create_time'],format="%d/%m/%Y")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    799                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)
    800     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
--> 801         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    802         if not cache_array.empty:
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    176         unique_dates = unique(arg)
    177         if len(unique_dates) < len(arg):
--> 178             cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
    179             cache_array = Series(cache_dates, index=unique_dates)
    180     return cache_array

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    458                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dta, name=name)
    459             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 460                 raise e
    461 
    462     if result is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    421             if result is None:
    422                 try:
--> 423                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
    424                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    425                     )

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '#VALOR!' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)
```

But if I do the same thing on the active_time, no error whatsoever.

My question is, how do I find this error in my database (create_time) using pandas? I tried to find this error on excel and didn't find anything. The csv file has more than 500k lines.

Here is a sample of my csv file:

```
owner_id,create_time,active_time
123,05/10/2021,05/10/2021
123,04/10/2021,04/10/2021
234,25/08/2021,25/08/2021
345,17/08/2021,02/10/2021
456,16/10/2020,24/09/2021
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
pf.loc[pf['create_time']=='#VALOR!']
```